# Moving on the map in navigation mode - Skobbler map Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, skmaps

As soon as the app starts, I need to start free navigation mode in order to be notified about streetType changes.

However, there are cases where certain Annotations are placed on the map, and user should be able to move around on the map, away from user's current location, and browse those annotations.

It's possible to zoom in and out, while in navigation mode, but is it possible to move around the map ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if this is possible if you enable panning after you startNavigation (see the enterPanningState code in the demo project).

Something like:

```
- (void)enterPanningState {
    [self showPanningUI];

    self.mapView.settings.followUserPosition = NO;
    self.mapView.settings.displayMode = SKMapDisplayMode2D;
}
```